# Regex on Python 2.7 causing problems on finding text in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, text

As like as the title i have a little problem with regex...

I have a string called "result" that has got the text: "Name: John Surname: Legend". I have to extract only the Name .

`print re.search('Name: (.+?) Surname: %s' % song, result).group(1)`

But it doesn't return anything... I have never used regex so i'm a little noob with it :'(

Comment: what is the value of variable `song`

Comment: the value is: "All of me"

Comment: try playing around with https://regex101.com/#python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: s = "Name: John Surname: Legend"

In [2]: re.search('Name:\s+(.+)\sSurname:\s+(.+)',s).groups()
Out[2]: ('John', 'Legend')

In [3]: re.search('Name:\s+(.+)\sSurname:\s+(.+)',s).group(1)
Out[3]: 'John'
```

Comment: here is what happens when i try your code .-.   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: **EDIT** it works...  mea culpa... i don't used in the "In [3]" the final ".group(1)" @Aviad